# Prove or Disprove the following statemnet

Tags: totient-function, primitive-roots

Prove or Disprove the following statement:
For each integer n>1 and each divisor d of φ(n), there is an integer a of order d modulo n.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a small example, say $n=6$ to see if you can get some insight?

Comment: I tried n=6 then I find a=7 satisfy this statement. But I do not know if there exist a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in general not true. Note that $\varphi(8)=4$, but there are no elements of order $4$ modulo $8$.

**Remark:** There is an element of order $\varphi(n)$ modulo $n$ precisely if $n=1$, $2$, $4$, or $p^k$ or $2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime.